# Why does making this expression more complex speed up the call to `Probability`?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have the following code:

```
aucs = Block[{p = 1.}, 
 Table[Probability[
   x[1] + z[1] > (x[2] + z[2]) (2 b - 1) \[Conditioned] 
    x[1] > x[2], {x[1] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
    x[2] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
    z[1] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]], 
    z[2] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]], 
    b \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[p]}], {\[Sigma], 1, 10, 
   1}]]
```

which returns within a few seconds. A very similar piece of code which should be equivalent as far as I can tell, takes much longer to return (actually I don't know how long it takes since I never saw it return a value):

```
Table[Probability[
  x[1] + z[1] > x[2] + z[2] \[Conditioned] 
   x[1] > x[2], {x[1] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
   x[2] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
   z[1] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]], 
   z[2] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]]}], {\[Sigma], 
  1, 10, 1}]
```

Any idea what the issue might be? In the first case, `b` is always `1` so the two expressions should be equivalent.

Comment: This is one for the statisticians probably, but it seems the first expression has a simple analytic form while the second does not (or at least Mathematica's symbolic manipulation stuff doesn't find it). Similarly, `NProbability` complains about poorly conditioned integrals in the second case

Comment: I'm pretty confident that the two expressions are equivalent from a theoretical perspective.

Comment: I think @b3m2a1 has supplied the answer.  As an alternative if you simplify the second table to the theoretically equivalent statement `Table[Probability[x[1] > x[2] + z21 \[Conditioned] x[1] > x[2], {x[1] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], x[2] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], z21 \[Distributed]  NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[2] \[Sigma]]}], {\[Sigma], 1, 10, 1}]//N`, you'll get the same result as the first table (but taking about a minute to complete).  Your first table even works without having to specify a value for $p$.

Comment: any idea why? or how might i find out why?